# Copy/paste the JOIN settings in the layer properties from a layer to another like you do with styles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, style, attribute-joins

I have a project with many layers that have the same columns, I need to copy paste a join with a table to each of those layers, but the copy/paste style with "JOIN" settings doesn't work.

Is there a way to perform this task auto or semiautomatically?

Basically every single layer has to be joined with a table, but I don't want to do it manually for every single layer.

Answer (score 1):

The following PyQGIS code might solve this challenge for you:

```
# Set the original layer containing the join to be copied to other layers
sourceLayer = iface.activeLayer()
# The join properties to be copied (=a list of joins)
joinsToCopy = sourceLayer.vectorJoins()

# Loop over all layers in the project
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # Confirm that the layer is not the source layer and that it is a QgsVectorLayer
    if layer != sourceLayer and layer.type() == 0:
        # Copy all joins to the current layer
        for joinToCopy in joinsToCopy:
            layer.addJoin(joinToCopy)
```